# CakePHP 2.2.0 Multi-tree Reordering performance

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, optimization, tree

I'm using a CakePHP multi-tree behaviour to store a structure of categories for a `site_id`. Each `site_id` has it's own tree.

There is currently only 119 records in the database, split across 8 different `site_id`. However, when I wish to re-order the tree for a particular `site_id` I run the following code:

```
$this->Category->recursive = -1;
$this->Category->reorder(array('id' => $last_category['Category']['parent_id'], 'field' => 'order', 'order' => 'asc'));
```

This currently takes 10-12 seconds to execute and I can't figure out what I can do to optimise this?

Tree behaviour code I'm using: http://pastebin.com/Xhf1LAgQ

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're not using correct indexes for your database tables. Add indexes.

Comment: I've added indexes on the columns which are used for the searching - that still doesn't improve it. It was the first optimisation I've tried. :(

Answer (score 0):

The Tree behaviour of cakephp is based on the Modified Preorder Tree Traversal paradigm.

Somebody already worked on performances of the cakphp tree behaviour, however the source code is no longer available. Please share it if you discover it :
https://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/10-b_tree-behavior-for-bigger-faster-trees

Comment: Would this be [it](https://github.com/CakeDC/utils/blob/develop/Model/Behavior/BtreeBehavior.php)?